# Как применить стили к последней строке

Tags: css

В css существует прекрасный псевдоэлемент ::first-line, который применяет стили к первой строке текста. Но есть ли способ по такому же принципу применить стили к последней?

Comment: Такого селектора не существует.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В CSS такой возможности, к сожалению, нет.

Вот вариант JavaScript:

```js
var html = document.getElementById('elem').innerHTML.split(/\r?\n/);
alert(html[html.length - 1]);
```

```html
<p id="elem">Я помню чудное мгновенье:<br>
Передо мной явилась ты,<br>
Как мимолетное виденье,<br>
Как гений чистой красоты.</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
text-align-last
```

Задаёт выравнивание последней строки блока текста.